# Is server side rendering good for web apps or only static?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, create-react-app

I am new to React and considering **SSR with Next.js** vs. **CSR** with `create-react-app`. Because I am building a web app, I've heard people say that **CSR** is better. As opposed to a static website, where **SSR** clearly has advantages.

**What are the benefits of `create-react-app` over Next.js and vice versa for a web app?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSR is better if your website has a lot of dynamic content, so when some UI changes you don't have to reload the whole website again. SSR renders the whole page for every page on server so it is a lot of resource consumption.
But SSR is better for crawling because for CSR, Google needs to render your page on their side, while it's much faster if it is SSR (the whole page is there already).
More on this: https://medium.com/@rohit_/ssr-vs-csr-the-ever-on-going-debate-e124021bbdb6

Comment: Thanks for the response... let's say I'm making a web app that let's you search for images. Wouldn't SSR not be faster because you still have to make API calls to fetch images? So would CSR be just as fast as SSR in this case?

Comment: If my knowledge is correct, in SSR you would have to reload the whole page with the images, while in CSR you only have to load the images

Comment: So in this case would you use CSR? I'm building a basic web app that just needs to load data with an API to load the page... could you update your answer with the pros and cons of each for this? I have marked as answer. REALLY appreciate your help!!

Comment: You could refer to pros and cons in the link I provided. From personal experience, most of the apps that I have involved all used CSR